# CakePHP3.1: disable options in a select input

Tags: forms, cakephp, html-select, disabled-input, cakephp-3.1

I want to disable options in a select input so I tried:

```
echo $this->Form->select("status", 
    [
    'options' => $status, 
    'value' => $order->status, 
    'label' => false, 
    'disabled' => [1, 2]
    ]);
```

But it doesn't generate any `disabled` statement in html code.

What's my mistake?

Comment: You should have a closer look at the docs and check the correct signature for `FormHelper::select()`. http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#_select | http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-select-pickers

Comment: @ndm, hum well sorry, I made a confusion between ``input()`` and ``select()`` syntaxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct way to set the attributes to the select's options is to pass an array like this

```
$options = [
    [ 'text' => 'option 1', 'value' => 'value 1', 'disabled' => true],
    [ 'text' => 'option 2', 'value' => 'value 2', 'disabled' => true],
    [ 'text' => 'option 3', 'value' => 'value 3'],
    [ 'text' => 'option 4', 'value' => 'value 4']
];

echo $this->Form->select(
    'status', 
    $options, 
    ['value' => $order->status, 'label' => false]
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use input function of FormHelper and set type = "select"
.My sample(only selectable Three)

```
$status = [1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two', 3 => 'Three'];
echo $this->Form->input("status", 
    [
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => $status, 
    'label' => false, 
    'disabled' => [1, 2]
    ]
);
```